# Tourist visa processing times at the Italian consulate in San Francisco

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, tourist-visas, san-francisco

I will be travelling to Italy on Nov 30th and the earliest appointment I can get at the Italian consulate for a tourist visa is Nov 4th. The consulate website says it takes 7-15 days to issue visas.

Anyone has any recent experience regarding how long it took them to get their passport back with stamped visa from the day when the passport was submitted to the consulate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Yelp is good for this](http://www.yelp.com/biz/consulate-general-of-italy-san-francisco) - reviews on there (well aside from the usual angry people) indicate that in person the whole process takes 10-20 minutes:

> The lady at the front was very helpful as well. We were done with the
>   whole process in less than 10 minutes!
>
> The whole process took less than 15 minutes.
>
> He was very knowledgeable and guided me through the process and got
>   the document ready for me in few minutes. I was in and out in fifteen
>   minutes.

And that after that, they time to receive passports:

> they mailed my passport with visa the very next day.
>
> I even got my passport mailed back within 2 days.
>
> The passports arrived with the visa in under 24 hours. Overall a 5
>   star experience.
>
> was told the processing time would be between 3-5 days. Got my visa on
>   the 5th day.

So although the website says 7-15 days, they may be covering themselves - it looks like generally you can probably expect it back in under a week. However, never assume that - if it takes longer, they'll just point you to the official time.

Comment: I suppose thatthe applicant's citizenship and the nature of the application have some bearing on the processing time.

Comment: @phoog presumably they also have busy periods / staff holidays etc too.